# Stop/destroy Magnific Popup in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, magnific-popup

I want to prevent magnificPopup dialog from displaying when I click a button and when no checkboxes are checked.

Here is what I have tried already:

```
$('[id$=DeleteSelectedItems]').click(function (evt) {
  if ($("#datatable :checked").length == 0) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    $.magnificPopup.remove(); //prevent dialog popup if no checkbox selected
  }
});
```

The above code is doing what I want except $.magnificPopup.remove(); is not a valid function.

[image: magnificPopup.remove i snot valid]

So although $.magnificPopup.remove(); prevents the popup from showing, (because it breaks the JavaScript!) it is not a valid function and I get an error in my console when testing this. I have tried $.magnificPopup.destroy(); and $.magnificPopup.stop(); but they are also not valid.

Many thanks for any help you can provide with this!

Comment: MagnificPopup has no `remove()`, `destroy()` or `stop()` methods. If you check the [documentation](https://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/documentation.html#public-methods), the closest you have is `close()`, but I'm not sure even that does what you're expecting

Comment: You can also use this method to destroy Magnific Popup: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73212892/destroy-magnificpopup-image-gallery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for your replies. I ended up using $.magnificPopup.close(); but, importantly, I put my code ***after*** the initialisation of magnific popup. Previously, I had it before the initialisation. Stupid mistake! So my working jQuery is:

```
// initialise magnific popup
$('.open-popup-link').magnificPopup({
   type: 'inline',
   midClick: true
});

//don't fire the delete button if no checkbox selected in table with id of datatable
$('[id$=DeleteSelectedItems]').click(function (evt) {
   if ($("#datatable :checked").length == 0) {
       evt.preventDefault();
       $.magnificPopup.close(); //prevent dialog popup if no checkbox selected
    }
});
```

Many thanks for pointing me in the right direction! : )

Answer (score 1):

Maybe *evt.preventDefault();* is enough to stop the popup showing, and you can remove the line of code $.magnificPopup.remove(); avoiding in this way the error in the console.

Comment: Many thanks - removing evt.preventDefault(); didn't solve the issue but I figured it the problem eventually. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

**This is how to destroy magnificPopup** according to the HTML markup in the snippet below:

```
    $.magnificPopup.close();
    $('.thumbs').off('click');
    $('.thumbs a').off('click');
```

```js
// initialize magnificPopup
function initMagnificPopup() {
  $('.thumbs').magnificPopup({
    type: 'image',
    delegate: 'a',
    gallery: {
      enabled: true
    }
  });
}

// destroy magnificPopup
function destroyMagnificPopup() {
  $.magnificPopup.close();
  $('.thumbs').off('click');
  $('.thumbs a').off('click');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/magnific-popup.js/1.1.0/magnific-popup.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/magnific-popup.js/1.1.0/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" onclick="initMagnificPopup()">initialize magnificPopup</button>

<div class="thumbs">
    <a href="https://picsum.photos/id/237/800.jpg" target="_blank">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/100.jpg">
    </a>
    
    <a href="https://picsum.photos/id/1003/800.jpg" target="_blank">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1003/100.jpg">
    </a>
    
    <a href="https://picsum.photos/id/1011/800.jpg" target="_blank">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1011/100.jpg">
    </a>
    
    <a href="https://picsum.photos/id/1025/800.jpg" target="_blank">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1025/100.jpg">
    </a>
</div>

<button type="button" onclick="destroyMagnificPopup()">destroy magnificPopup</button>
```